# Photoshop path won't mirror exactly

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, transform

I am new to doing vector art with Photoshop and am encountering a weird problem. I've been using paths to define my shapes, and using free transform to mirror them and drag them over to look reflected across the middle of the canvas. This was working until recently; I dragged the duplicated path over and it somehow doesn't match pixel for pixel. Could someone explain a way to fix this? Am I encountering this problem because I'm just misusing the program?

I've attached an example: the left side is what I'm dragging and the white line is down the middle of the canvas. I know it looks like I may have just moved it up or down by accident, but I checked and that isn't the case. [image]

Comment: You're creating vector art, but viewing raster interpretation of those vectors. Are your paths mirrored identically in the manner you expect?

Comment: Don't use Photoshop for vector work. It's not the right kind of software.  Photoshop is a raster image editor with very limited vector support.  Instead, use a vector image editor such as Illustrator, CorelDraw, Affinity Designer, Inkscape (which is free), etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "white line"? Is it the guideline from the ruler?

Comment: Yes I mean the guideline, that was unclear in retrospect with the white curves. I decided to bite the bullet and try learning Illustrator and the pen tool seems to be basically the same. The image looks properly symmetrical now too. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "flip horizontal".

For example:
Here is the original image.

[image: Original image]

Duplicate the image and mask it if needed. In this example, I decided to do it right down the middle like a mirror.

[image: Duplicate and mask]

Duplicate the new layer including the mask, then go to Edit >> Transform (not Free Transform) >> Flip horizontally

[image: Flip horizontally]

That edit only affects the layer you have currently selected, so make sure you check where the layers are listed and see if one of the duplicates is selected.

This completes the reflection, however, if working with vectors that are imported, they are no longer vectors once it is imported into Photoshop. Instead, if you have access to Illustrator, there is a different way of doing this which includes the tool called reflect tool or using the transform effect on the path.

Comment: Yeah this is what I was doing, it just didn't mirror the pixels perfectly regardless.

Comment: @Radagast the problem in your case is that your vectors dont hit the pixels exactly on the edge. Photoshop only mirrors whole pixels. instead you should probably scale a copy of path by -100% on the x axis. Anyway its q really really bad idea to draw vectors as a pixel image as you get into corner cases where your interpretation may not be the only valid one thus now you have a point ehere you can unintentionally screw up.